# How to receive POST requests on AWS Beanstalk on a different resource than root?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'd like to run a webhook proxy on AWS Beanstalk. The service sends POST requests, which need to be modified and forwarded by the proxy.

The URL to which the `POST` would be directed is something like `webhook-proxy.com/<randomid>`

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. When the webhook is sent to the proxy I only get the following error message:

> MethodNotAllowed - The specified method is not allowed against this resource

I found that AWS only allows `POST` requests to the root resource. Are there any settings which need to be applied on the AWS side to enable `POST` to this resource?